# AttributeError: 'datetime.timedelta' object has no attribute 'split'

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, split, timedelta

i am trying to get number of difference in hours from datetime by below code
'''

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date 
from datetime import time
from datetime import timedelta
import sys
a = date.today()
b = datetime.now()
print("Today is :" +str(b))
q = int(input("enter your birth month :"))

w = int(input("enter your brth day :"))
my_bday = date(a.year,q,w)
#print(my_bday)
if my_bday < a :
     my_bday = my_bday.replace(year = a.year +1)

time_to_bday = abs (a -my_bday)
#print("The number of days remaining for your bday is :" +time_to_bday)
o = time_to_bday.split(' ')
z = o[0]
k = timedelta(days = z)
print("Time remaining for your bday is : " +str(b + k))
```

Here split is not working and giving below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "f:/Ch2/practise.py", line 96, in <module>
    o = time_to_bday.split(' ')
AttributeError: 'datetime.timedelta' object has no attribute 'split'
```

I double checked the o/p of code till time_to_bday as below :

```
PS F:\Ch2> & "C:/Users/sai kiran/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/python.exe" f:/Ch2/practise.py
Today is :2021-05-01 20:32:08.677781
enter your birth month :11
enter your brth day :17
200 days, 0:00:00
```

Comment: What is the expected output ? What isn't good with `200 days, 0:00:00` ?

Comment: `str(time_to_bday).split(' ')`?

Comment: i am just curious why this is not working with split method . if it works please guide .else please correct me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Timedelta` isn't a `str` so doesn't have `spilit()`.
`print()` converts it to `str`.
You need to call `o=str(o)` for example

Answer (score 0):

You have already calculated delta in time, It's not string anymore

time_to_bday is timedelta object, you can directly get days as below

time_to_bday.days

if you want to print in hours you can print using time_to_bday.days * 24

```
From your code ::
enter your birth month :4
enter your brth day :17

    >> time_to_bday.days
    350
```